Intel Driver & Support Assistant wants new network drivers but installation fails
Intel Driver and Support Assistant says that I should update my network drivers.  Unfortunately, it fails to install and says No Intel Network Connections.
Device Manager says I already have the latest drivers.
Advice on whether to leave "as-is" or try to install new Intel drivers.







Your adapter does not support the driver you are attempting to install. This is what you are attempting to download.  Can you confirm?

29.1 didn't contain any updates that were applicable to Windows 10.  29.1 is also not the current driver release. 98% of the changes for 29.1 were only applicable for Linux.

Ramhound:  Intel's Driver and Support Assistant says there is one software update available for my system, and it chose 29.1 as the correct one to install.  Device Manager and the documentation seem to indicate that Intel's software is incorrect.  I am just trying to clarify if a driver update is needed or not.

The assistant is wrong. I found the driver in the screenshot; it does not support the adapter you are using. Have you tried to download and install the correct driver which is compatible with your device manually?

Ramhound, maybe you can help me out.  How do I go about determining the latest driver for my device?
Is it this one?https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download/15084/intel-ethernet-adapter-complete-driver-pack.html

I just went to the website and searched for your device, but I asked if I had found the driver, you were attempting to install and you have neither confirmed that is or isn’t the case. So I am reluctant to do any additional research on the subject. I also don’t believe an answer with a link to a driver, on a specific date is that helpful, since all I did was search for the device on the Intel website. Yes; That’s the same driver I found. No, it’s not required, unless your missing a feature the adapter does support, release notes from the last 5 releases were primarily focused on Linux.

Thank you for your help.  I am not going to download a new driver.  The old one works fine.

Same issue for me.
